# CakePHP4 - Authentication - How to change default userModel?

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm following this tutorial to set up Authentication https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html with CakePHP4.

The table where my users are stored is not called "users" so when I try to log in it gives me this error:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.users'
```

Where can I specify the userModel? In which file should it be set up? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure the respective resolver accordingly, in this case the ORM resolver.

Resolvers are used by identifiers, which accept resolver configuration via the `resolver` option. So for example for the password identifier, you could do it like this:

```php
$service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [
    'resolver' => [
        'className' => 'Authentication.Orm',
        'userModel' => 'YourCustomModelName',
    ],
    // ....
]);
```

Note that it's necessary to pass the class name too when passing an array of resolver configuration, as the default configuration is just a string (the resolver class name), so it will not merge with the defaults, but overwrite them!

See also

- **[Authentication Cookbook > Identifiers](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/identifiers.html)**
- **[Authentication Cookbook > Identifiers > Identity resolvers](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/identifiers.html#identity-resolvers)**