# Cakephp authentication plugin how can I implement login in admin prefix?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to implement cakephp [authentication plugin](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html) in admin prefix

Route I have written for admin prefix

```
$routes->prefix('admin', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/',['controller'=>'AdminUsers','action'=>'login']);
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

In application.php , I have followed everything That mentioned in authentication documentation

```
public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
{

        $authenticationService = new AuthenticationService([
            'unauthenticatedRedirect' => Router::url('/admin'),
            'queryParam' => 'redirect',
        ]);

        // Load identifiers, ensure we check email and password fields
        $authenticationService->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password',
            ]
        ]);

        // Load the authenticators, you want session first
        $authenticationService->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
        // Configure form data check to pick email and password
        $authenticationService->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password',
            ],
            'userModel' => 'AdminUsers',
            'loginUrl' => Router::url('/admin'),
        ]);

        return $authenticationService;
}
```

I have changed users model to `AdminUsers` for database table admin_users

Now in `admin/appController.php`

I have loadComponent in initialize method

```
$this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication');
```

In before filter method I have added

```
$this->Authentication->allowUnauthenticated(['login']);
```

Now after submit login form I am getting error

```
Table class for alias Users could not be found.
```

In getAuthenticationService method I have changed model Users to AdminUsers. Why it's going for Users model rather then AdminUsers model ?

My `Table/AdminUsersTable.php` table class look likes

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class AdminUsersTable extends Table
{
    
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('admin_users');
--------
```

After ndm comment I am able to change default model in application.php , But how can I change it in Admin/AppController.php ? Code that I have tried.

```
public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event)
    {
        
        $service = new AuthenticationService();

        $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [
            'resolver' => [
                'className' => 'Authentication.Orm',
                'userModel' => 'AdminUsers',
            ],
        ]);

        $this->Authentication->allowUnauthenticated(['login','signup']);
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('admin');

    }
```

Comment: What your AdminUsers model looks like?

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232188/cakephp4-authentication-how-to-change-default-usermodel/65266354#65266354**

Comment: @ndm how can I change it in admin/AppController.php rather then application.php 
I have tried in Admin/AppController , beforeFilter method but model is not changing.

Comment: You can't, authentication happens in the middleware layer, before the controller code runs. If you want different configuration for specific routes, then you should either using [**scoped middleware**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#route-scoped-middleware), or configure the authentication service dynamically depending on the request target (the `$request` argument for `getAuthenticationService()` has all the info you need).